# How do I prove the following identity: $\sin^3x + \cos^3x + \sin x\cos^2x + \sin^2x\cos x = \sin x+\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I believe I need to factor the first two cubed terms, but it winds up, at least to me, a little convoluted. Maybe I'm on the right path, but I am unsure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Group the left hand side as $(\sin^3 x + \sin x \cos^2 x) + (\cos^3 x +  \sin^2 x \cos x)$ and see what you can factor out from each group.

Comment: YOu can always use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ to replace $\sin^2 x$ with $1 - \cos^2 x$ (and vice versa).  So for example $\sin x\cos^2 x= \sin x(1- \sin^2 x) = \sin x - \sin^3 x$ and ... well, just eyeballing it I think everything is going to just fall out.

Comment: ... to follow.  $\sin x \cos^2 x = \sin x (1- \sin^2 x) = \sin x -\sin^3 x$ and likewise $\cos x \sin^2 x= \cos x (1-\cos^2 x) = \cos x - \cos^3 x$ so $\sin^3x + \cos^3x + \sin x\cos^2x + \sin^2x\cos x = \sin^3x +\cos^3x + (\sin x - \sin^3 x) + (\cos x- \cos^3 x) =(\sin^3x-\sin^3x) + (\cos^3 x - \cos^3 x) + \sin x + \cos x = \sin x + \cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a,b$, we have
$$a^3+b^3+ab^2+a^2b=(a^2+b^2)(a+b)$$
Now put $a=\sin x, b=\cos x$ and use $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$.

Comment: Yes. This makes sense. It's very simple but I just couldn't get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\sin^3x$ as $\sin x \sin^2 x$. Then,

$$ \sin^3 x + \sin x \cos^2 x = \sin x ( \sin^2x + \cos^2x) = \sin x. $$

If you do the same for $\cos^3 x$, you have that

$$ \cos^3 x + \cos x \sin^2 x = \cos x (\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x) = \cos x.$$

Summing both these equalities, you obtain

$$ \sin^3 x + \sin x \cos^2 x + \cos^3 x + \cos x \sin^2 x = \sin x + \cos x.$$

Comment: Very good. I like it. It's arrived at differently than another answer here, but both are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the right hand side of the equation you can multiply ($\sin^2x+\cos^2x$) as it is equivalent to 1 and hence both sides of the equation become equal.